# Why do those useless instruction are in Rust final binary?

Tags: disassembly, compilers, compiler-optimization

I am currently reversing RUST binaries, and I often come across this block of instruction :

```
.text:000055F4BFB943F2 db      2Eh
.text:000055F4BFB943F2 nop     word ptr [rax+rax+00000000h]
.text:000055F4BFB943FC nop     dword ptr [rax+00h]
```

Which probably does nothing. I can see the rogue byte at the beginning, but pressing `C` on IDA to disassemble from there gives no result. Thus, I am wondering why rust compiler create those instructions as they appear to be useless.

Comment: "Block of instructions": are you sure this appears inside an executable flow? It looks like inter-function *padding*, nothing more. Padding is not "useless", although the instructions themself are. (And that "rogue byte" is just a segment override.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are instructions used for alignment. You can see that the last instruction ends on a 16-byte boundary (`000055F4BFB94400`).